# Accessing capture groups in AS3 RegEx

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, capture-group

I have a document that looks like this:

```
public class FunctionalColors {

    private static var colorArray:Array = new Array();

    public function FunctionalColors(e:Enforcer) {

    }

    public static function get colors():Array {
        if (colorArray.length == 0) {
            colorArray["DIRECT CABLING"] = 0x61568F;
            colorArray["10Base2 ETHERNET"] = 0x37699B;
            colorArray["10BaseT ETHERNET"] = 0x6699FF;
            colorArray["1 Gb Ethernet"] = 0x4169FF;
            colorArray["10 Gb Ethernet"] = 0x00CDD0;
        }

        return colorArray;
    }
}
```

I need to pull out the keys of the colorArray (i.e. "Direct Cabling", "10Base2 Ethernet", etc.) and store them in another array. I have a regular expression that looks like this

`var colorsRegEx:RegExp = new RegExp(/colorArray\[\"(.*)\"\]/g);`

This matches the entirety of, for example, "colorArray["DIRECT CABLING"]." Is there a way to grab just the (.*) capture group so I just have the dictionary key? It looks like if you're using the String.replace method, you can target particular capture groups, but I'm not seeing a way to pull them out to use them elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Use `m = colorsRegEx.exec(string)` in a loop and access the `m[1]` value.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Wiktor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise to use lazy matching `.*?` in the pattern in order not to overmatch (`*?` quantifier is called lazy and will only match as few occurrences of the quantified subpattern as possible), and to grab all the occurrences of captured values, you may use a `while` loop inside which will call the `re.exec` until no match:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /colorArray\["(.*?)"]/g; 
var str:String = "<<YOUR_STRING_HERE>>"; 
var result:Array = [];
var m:Array = pattern.exec(str); 
while (m != null) 
{ 
    result.push(m[1]);
    m = pattern.exec(str); 
}
```

Note also that you do not have to use a RegExp constructor notation when using a *static* regex pattern (i.e. using no variables to build it), use the simple `/.../` regex literal notation.